# Use Range Slider as Output

Tags: javascript, html, rangeslider

How can I have a Range Slider show the results of an input?

Example: If the input it 5 X 5 how do I get the Range Slider to show 25?

Comment: so you want to set the value of a range slider programmatically? ie set it's value to "25" and have that visible by the position of the input's gripper on the slider bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can programmatically set the value of a "range" slider input element by setting it's `value` field like so:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('my-input');

// Add keyup listener to input to allow interactive updates of
// range slider
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  
  // Get range slider element
  const rangeSlider = document.getElementById('my-range-slider');
   
  // Set value of range slider from input value
  rangeSlider.value = input.value * input.value 
})
```

```html
<p>Input</p>
<div>
<input id="my-input" />
</div>
<p>Output = Input x Input</p>
<div>
<span>0</span>
<input id="my-range-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1000" />
<span>1000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: YES, Thank you very much.